# How does Inheritance work with templates in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

This simple inheritance structure works fine

```
class Parent{
protected:
    int x;
};

class Child : public Parent{
public:
    int func() {return x;}
};
```

Meanwhile, the code below which is nearly identical doesn't work. Why is this?

```
template<typename T>class T_Parent{
protected:
    int x;
};

template<typename T> class T_Child : public T_Parent <T>{
public:
    int func() {return x;}
};
```

EDIT: the error is `use of undeclared identifier 'x'` despite x being defined in the `Parent` class

Comment: How doesn't it work?